# Mongodb 3.2 user authentication backward compatibility

Tags: mongodb, scala, backwards-compatibility

Here's the thing: I have upgraded mongodb from 2.6 (to 3.0 and then) to 3.2. Applications that I use could connect to these databases freely, but if I install mongodb in 3.2 (not upgrading from older ones) I can login only without password (scala driver 1.0 in these apps). I'm pretty sure that is the driver's fault.

Here's how it works:

- upgrade from 2.6 to 3.2 -> mongo client connects (with password and without) and app connects (with password or without)
- fresh 3.2 -> mongo client connects (with password and without) but app connects only without password. I don't think its the 'authorization: enabled' problem - I have tried with and without that option.

Is it possible to install some plugins or anything to add backward compability? It's impossible to change driver in app.

Or maybe I'm wrong and the driver is not the problem?

Comment: Have you checked whether your user accounts are using MONGODB-CR authentication or SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication? Both the user accounts in the upgraded database and in the fresh database.

Comment: upgrade DB is in legacy auth, aka CR, whereas fresh DB is in SCRAM, and there is no way from the driver/client to know that, so it may fail to use the right auth algo. Better to indicate it explicitly.

Comment: Yep, you were right. That's the issue with the SCRAM. So i have no choice but to change the authorization method and recreate users. Thank you so much for helping me.